# How to make select parts of composite models static

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In a composite model, is it possible to make one part of a model static while make other parts dynamic?

I'd like to position a platform in a static position a few meters in the air, while allowing actuators attached below it to move, simulating the platform being mounted to a ceiling. I tried making the platform model static, while making the actuator models dynamic, but Gazebo seems to interpret the entire model as static if even one part is static.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8434/how-to-make-select-parts-of-composite-models-static/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently, it isn't possible to make some links of a model static while the others are dynamic.

A workaround would be to fix the platform to the world with a joint that has very low limits to make it almost fixed (you can try making it completely fixed by setting upper and lower limits == 0, but that might cause instability). I'd also make it very heavy to make sure it doesn't move. See the [foosball](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/86ac95428490bccb5b4b09c52cc798f7a0768451/foosball/model.sdf?at=foosball#cl-111) table as an example, it would look something like this:

```
<joint name='platform_world' type='prismatic'>
  <parent>world</parent>
  <child>platform</child>
  <axis>
    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
    <limit>
      <lower>0</lower>
      <upper>0.1</upper>
    </limit>
  </axis>
</joint>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1